# How do I prerender just one route at a time with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I use `npm run prerender` to get static HTML files for my routes and everything works just fine. I prerender, copy everything from the browser directory to the server and all is great.

However, in the future I would like to be able to prerender just one route at a time and reuse the old JS and CSS that is already deployed. Imagine you have a shop or news site. You can not just update the whole website because of one added item or article.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the hashes of the files stay the same when nothing changes. I thought those were random hashes. They are probably computed based on content.

That means I can run `ng run <app-name>:prerender --no-guess-routes --routes /product/1 /product/2` and get single routes.